# Accessing object inside another object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have a following object:

```
DOMAIN_ROLE:{
    type: "Domain"
    DomainName: "XYZ"
    DomainCode: 21
    Title: "People Role"
    CodedValues:{
        1: {Code: 1, Label: "Land"},
        2: {Code: 2, Label: "Forest"},
        3: {Code: 3, Label: "Public"},
        4: {Code: 4, Label: "Single"},
        5: {Code: 5, Label: "Private"}
       }
}
```

What I am trying to do is map through this data where object named "CodedValues" has index of 1 , 2 and 5 as shown below:

```
{Object.keys(DOMAIN_ROLE.CodedValues[1,2,5]).map(key =>{
          return (
          <div>...</div>
            );
}
```

The problem is while mapping through, the "key" get's the value as "Code" instead of number i.e. 1,2,3...
it seems key becomes key = CodedValues.Code, where I want to work as key = 1, key = 2, key = 5

Tried to explain in best possible way. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: can you provide working example for the code https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-sea-b8prb

Comment: You cannot access multiple indices at once. What are you trying to do? Display only the CodedValues on indices 1, 2, and 5? Is CodedValues an array?

Comment: how do you want to return the html in render ..please mention in the question please

Comment: @AgusZubiaga CodedValues is and object, as shown. and Yes just want to show CodedValues on indices 1,2 and 5

Comment: Both the keys of `CodedValues` and the values of `Code` are the same except the keys get converted to string, so how do you know which is what? Also what does `CodedValues[1,2,5]` do?

Comment: Which are you want to get as output? something like ```[1, 2, 5]``` or ```[{Code: 1, Label: "Land"},{Code: 2, Label: "Forest"},{Code: 5, Label: "Private"}]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DOMAIN_ROLE.CodedValues[1,2,5]` does not actually what you expect (get items with keys 1,2 and 5). You have to get all the keys and filter them and use it:

```
Object.keys(DOMAIN_ROLE.CodedValues).filter(k => /* filter logic */).map(key => {
    // Use key here: DOMAIN_ROLE[key]
});
```

This is helpful if you want to filter your keys based on some logic. If you are going to hard-code the keys why not just use `['1', '2', '5'].map(key => { /**/ });` as @str metions in the comments.

Comment: Or just use `['1', '2', '5'].map(key => {/**/});` which does the same thing. But given how unclear the question is, an answer is probably not useful yet.

Comment: @Saravana Thanks alot for nice explanation

Answer (score 1):

```js
let DOMAIN_ROLE = {
    type: "Domain",
    DomainName: "XYZ",
    DomainCode: 21,
    Title: "People Role",
    CodedValues:{
        1: {Code: 1, Label: "Land"},
        2: {Code: 2, Label: "Forest"},
        3: {Code: 3, Label: "Public"},
        4: {Code: 4, Label: "Single"},
        5: {Code: 5, Label: "Private"}
       }
}

// you can use object destructuring to get the data by key.

const {1:first,2:second, 5:fifth} = DOMAIN_ROLE.CodedValues;

console.log(first,second, fifth)


//[first, second, fifth].map(()=>{})
```